# SQL select where column begins with Letters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table tbl1 with row of data:

```
ID       TIN     SSS
10001    none    1000-20
10002    69098   PRC
10003    69099   INC
```

I want to query the the Legal_Doc_No of each ID. The value of each ID is either the TIN or the SSS column.

How can I query the TIN and SSS column starting with letters (none) so that only values starting with numbers will be assigned to Legal_Doc_No

```
Select
ID,
'Legal_Doc_No' = case when TIN = Letter then SSS
 else TIN end
from tbl1
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most databases support `left()`, so you can do something like this:

```
select id,
       (case when left(time, 1) between 'a' and 'z' or left(time, 1) between 'A' and 'Z'
             then SSS else TIN
        end) as Legal_Doc_no
from tbl1;
```

Depending on the database, there might be other solutions.

In SQL Server, you can do:

```
select id,
       (case when time like '[a-z]%'
             then SSS else TIN
        end) as Legal_Doc_no
from tbl1;
```

If you have a case-sensitive collation, then you'll need to take that into account:

```
select id,
       (case when lower(time) like '[a-z]%'
             then SSS else TIN
        end) as Legal_Doc_no
from tbl1;
```

Answer (score 3):

The following solution should work assuming that either the `TIN` column or the `SSS` column, but not both, contains numeric digits (i.e. is in numeric format):

```
SELECT ID,
    CASE WHEN TIN LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN TIN ELSE SSS END AS Legal_Doc_No
FROM tbl1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
### To find words that start with the letter A
SELECT title
FROM films
WHERE title LIKE('A%');
```